# Find properties that are null for every JavaScript object in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, if I have a JavaScript array of objects such as:

```
var jsObjects = [
   {a: 1, b: 2, c: null, d: 3, e: null}, 
   {a: 3, b: null, c: null, d: 5, e: null}, 
   {a: null, b: 6, c: null, d: 3, e: null}, 
   {a: null, b: 8, c: null, d: 1, e: null}
];
```

I would expect the output to be ["c", "e"].

My current solution is to call a function for each column & loop through the jsObjects:

```
function isAllNull(col) {
    var allNulls = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    
       if (jsObjects[i].col != null) { 
             allNulls = false;
             break;
        }
      }
}
```

But I would like for this function to be more generic such that it will jsObjects with any number of arbitrary simple (i.e. not objects) properties. The objects in the array all have the same properties.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, are they always going to be `null` for each object in the array so you'd just have to check the first one?

Comment: @Nick - Updated post

Comment: Do you guarantee that each object in the array has the same properties?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie - Yes

Comment: I don't understand how is "["c", "e"]." the expected result when your question to find null property values in every object of the array [!]?

Comment: @BekimBacaj Every object in the array has null for property c and e. So, `["c", "e"]` should be the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you guarantee that each object in the array has the same properties then:

- take the keys from the first object in the array
- `reduce` the keys and test `every` key in the original array for `null`
- if `every` key returns true then include the key in the output

Example:

```js
var jsObjects = [
   {a: 1, b: 2, c: null, d: 3, e: null}, 
   {a: 3, b: null, c: null, d: 5, e: null}, 
   {a: null, b: 6, c: null, d: 3, e: null}, 
   {a: null, b: 8, c: null, d: 1, e: null}
];

function nullCols(arr) {
  var keys = Object.keys(arr[0]);
  var nulls = keys.reduce((output, key) => {
    if (arr.every(item => item[key] === null)) {
      output.push(key);
    }
    return output;
  }, []);
  return nulls;
}

console.log(nullCols(jsObjects));
```